# QScrollArea vertical sizePolicy - Fit contents up to maximum height

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qlayout

I've had a real challenge getting `QScrollArea` to take the minimum space possible up to a maximum height.

My GUI model is as follows: A `QScrollArea` contains a vertical layout which is populated with a widget of class `TableRow`. I want this class `TableRow` to take up the minimum height possible. It has a widget at the top which is always visible, and a `QScrollArea` below which has a label inside it whose visibility can be toggled. The label is for notes which may be 0 characters or may be infinite in length (hardware limitations aside).

I've found that for a label in class `TableRow` setting the vertical `sizePolicy` to `Fixed` will actually take up exactly how much it needs to fit all the contents (see:  [Qt Layout, resize to minimum after widget size changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14980620/qt-layout-resize-to-minimum-after-widget-size-changes)). However this doesn't appear to work with `QScrollArea`. In fact every `sizePolicy` I've tried keeps the `QScrollArea` at a fixed height; except for `Ignore`, but then the `QScrollArea` goes to a height of 0, regardless of its contents.

I've created a [git branch](https://github.com/Assimilater/Questions/tree/Qt/ScrollAreaMinimumSizePolicy/Qt) producing a simplified version of this problem.

Here is the result of applying a fixed vertical sizePolicy:
[image: Result of fixed vertical sizePolicy]

What I'm expecting from this test case:

- The first widget's height should be almost 30px (the height of the upper widget) only showing the borders for the `QLabel` and `QScrollArea`
- The second widget's height should be shorter than 130px (the maximum height of the `QScrollArea` being 100px) but large enough to show the label without scrolling
- The third widget's height should be 130px, and the scrollbar should appear (this part is correct in every case I've tried except for when the vertical `sizePolicy` is set to `Ignored` )

I understand I may need to override some things to make this work, as by itself it's not obvious why a QScrollArea's height might be dependent on its child widgets (which is probably why it was not designed to make this easy, or at least it seems like it wasn't).

However, I think the case I'm trying to make is common enough, and my current approach is justifiable. If there's another/better way to make an individual widget scroll after it reaches a maximum height I'm open to that as an answer, provided it meets the three conditions I'm expecting.

Comment: Have you tried setting size policies on the viewports instead of the scroll areas themselves?

Comment: Probably not. What's a viewport? :)

Comment: Google: The viewport is the widget inside the QScrollArea in which all child widgets are rendered? I have also tried adjusting this, yes. Currently I have it set for `Fixed`

Comment: If the viewport is a fixed size, it won't dynamically adjust the way you need it to. Try working with the layouts' `sizeConstraint` properties and the stretch, perhaps?

Comment: Do you have a suggested combination of sizeHint/sizeConstraint/stretch on the viewport/layout? My attempted combinations have been to no avail. I believe I need the viewport to be a fixed size though. As I learned from the SO Link I posted, fixed will actually assume the minimum space required. This appears to hold true for the viewport as well, from what I've been able to test. Also, forcing it smaller with a maximum size has no effect on the ScrollArea. Though I could be misinterpreting what I see when I debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels more like a hack than a solution, but it does work for me, at least in the short term. Because the text for lblNotes does not change runtime, I was able to add the following code in the constructor of my `TableRow` widget:

```
// Hack to resize QScrollAreas
ui->lblNotes->adjustSize(); // Otherwise lblNotes will think its height is still ~0px
int height = ui->lblNotes->height() + 12; // Borders and margins add up to 12px
if (height > 100) { height = 100; } // Cap the height at desired maximum value
ui->scrollArea->setFixedHeight(height);
```

Should I have to deal with the case of dynamically set text, I could wrap this in a function to be called anytime the text of lblNotes is set.

I'm still open to solutions that involve using the layout features Qt has natively as I believe that would be preferred if a solution exists. Some `QScrollArea` contents may not be as straight-forward to determine the height from in the future.